# Prop to detect if link is active in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, emotion

I have a `NavLink` which have child components

```
<NavLink
    className={StyledAppNavItem}
    activeClassName={StyledAppNavItemActive}
    to={link.path}
>
    <Icon size={28} icon={link.icon} color={isActive?'red':'blue'}/>
    <StyledAppNavName>{link.name}</StyledAppNavName>
</NavLink>
```

Like `activeClassName` is attached when the link is active, I need to detect if this link is active and send a prop to its child component `Icon`

Somewhat like `<Icon color={linkisActive?'red':'blue'}/>`

Comment: `console(this.props)` inside `child components` and see what you get there?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get `isActive` from `NavLink`. You need to create your custom `NavLink`. Something like this:

```
function MyNavLink() {
    return (
        <Route path={link.path} children={({ match }) => (
            <Link
                className={`${StyledAppNavItem} ${match ? StyledAppNavItemActive : ''}`}
                to={link.path}
            >
                <Icon size={28} icon={link.icon} color={match ? 'red' : 'blue'}/>
                <StyledAppNavName>{link.name}</StyledAppNavName>
            </Link>
        )} />
    );
}
```

Or you can just add Route to your current component:

```
<NavLink
    className={StyledAppNavItem}
    activeClassName={StyledAppNavItemActive}
    to={link.path}
>
    <Route path={link.path} children={({ match }) => (
        <Icon size={28} icon={link.icon} color={match?'red':'blue'}/>
    )} />
    <StyledAppNavName>{link.name}</StyledAppNavName>
</NavLink>
```

Comment: I can't create a custom component in my case, can I pass `match` without creating a custom component?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer - you can simply wrap your `<Icon />` with `<Route />`

Comment: got this error `error    Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags  react/no-children-prop`

Comment: It's an eslint warning. You can disable this rule in your .eslintrc file, or just for this file using comment: 
`/* eslint react/no-children-prop: "off" */` at the top of your file