# activeClassName not working for react router for variable path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

```html
 <li className="nav-item">
  <NavLink className="nav-link" to={"/QaManagement" + domainName}>
        <span className="Qimg" onClick={this.clicked}>
           <img src={imageVar.QA} alt="" />
        </span>
  </NavLink>
</li>
```

I want to change the image when the link is active, I can not use the exact property also as a domainName is a variable.

Comment: I have tried many things like using activeClassName with exact property and activeClassName="active" with onlyActiveOnIndex attribute etc but nothing is working

Comment: You will have to write a custom function. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747114/prop-to-detect-if-link-is-active-in-react) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue  using activeClassName with exact property and activeClassName="active" with onlyActiveOnIndex attribute and it worked for me